# Handling output buffers in emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, memory-management, emscripten

Lets say I have a C API as follows:

```
void get_result_buffer(context* ctx, void** result, size_t* result_size);
```

Where `context` is some arbitrary opaque context type holding state. The intended way to call this is

```
context* ctx = ...;

do_something_with_context(ctx, ...);

void* result_buffer = 0;
size_t result_buffer_size = 0;
get_result_buffer(ctx, &result_buffer, &result_buffer_size);

/* Now result_buffer and result_buffer_size are meaningful and populated with the results of having called `do_something_with_context`. */
```

The `result_buffer` is owned by the `context` object, so the caller doesn't need to free it. Now I'd like to be able to call `get_result_buffer` from Emscripten. I can easily enough set up `cwrap` for this, it looks something like:

```
wrap_get_result_buffer = something.cwrap(
    'get_result_buffer',
    null,
    ['number', 'number', 'number']
)
```

But I'm unclear how I can set things up so that the out parameters "work" in JS. Ideally, at the end, I'd have something that looks like a byte buffer containing a copy of the data pointed to by the `result` out parameter, with a length as described by the `result_size` out parameter.

It seems that the values that I pass in need to be allocated somehow, and then I would pass the resulting allocation handle in as the `number` type parameters, but I have no idea how to do that in the JS/Emscripten layer. Similarly, after the call, I'd expect that those values have now been updated by the transpiled C code, but I'm unclear on how to extract the now populated data into some sort of JS byte array.

Any guidance on how to do this or pointers to example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I figured this out. For future emscripteners, you want to do something like the following.

```
var out_data_ptr = Module._malloc(8)
var out_data_array = new Uint32Array(Module.HEAPU32.buffer, out_data_ptr, 2)
wrap_get_result_buffer(context, out_data_ptr, out_data_ptr + 4)
var response_uint8_array = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, out_data_array[0], out_data_array[1])
Module._free(out_data_ptr)
```

The theory of operations here is that we create a two element array that will store the 'slots' to be filled in by calling `get_result_buffer`, and then construct a view over that exposing it as two `number` compatible elements. We then pass those in to our `get_result_buffer` function as lifted above with `cwrap`. After that, the heap memory that the `context` refers to is reachable from those slots, which can then be used to construct a `Uint8Array` that provides JS level access to the bytes in the result.

Comment: @Alon Zakai - I'd be interested to know if the above solution seems correct to you.